# Как программно создать xml файл?

Tags: java, android

Пользуюсь xml разметкой через flipper:

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
int layouts[] = new int[]{R.layout.scr0, R.layout.scr1, R.layout.scr2, R.layout.scr3};
for (int layout : layouts) flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
```

Как программно создать xml файл, чтобы использовать его в этой конструкции?

Например файл с именем scr0.xml

Comment: Интересно узнать что Вы будете туда писать программно? Если  содержимое известно заранее - то проще сразу положить в "layout/". Если нет, то как Вы будете взаимодействовать с неизвестной компоновкой?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. Файлы разметки как и прочие ресурсы упаковываются в `apk` файл на этаппе компиляции. Изменять их, редактировать или добавлять новые на этапе исполнения нельзя.

Вам надо просто программно создать, наверное, разметку без использования `xml`. Типа как-то так:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
TextView tv = new TextView(context);
tv.setText("42");
ll.addView(tv);

View layouts[] = new View[]{ll};
for (View layout : layouts) flipper.addView(layout);
```